# Is there any way to make ReSharper folder's "Namespace Provider" property to false by default?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

By default ReSharper folder's "Namespace Provider" property defaults to true. I am generally want to be this property to be false. This means, every zillon times I create a new folder in my projects I have to set it manually false.

Is there any way to make ReSharper folder's "Namespace Provider" property to false by default?

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not about default value. It's only about a workaround.

These settings are stored in YourProject.csproj.DotSettings file for each folder in project. If "Namespace Provider" is set to **false** for **YourFolder**, the following record is added to file:

```
<s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/NamespaceProvider/NamespaceFoldersToSkip/=YourFolder/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
```

So you may make list of of your folders using Total Commander or similar tool and then add it to that file, or even do it automatically. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is still a manual method, which may be efficient for existing legacy projects, when I would like to add many folders at once.  However I want to add my folders instantly (one by one) as I developing the project